# App crashing after loging in using otp once and then after logout trying to go to login page again

Tags: android, firebase

App has stopped. Open app again.

This is my SignUp activity where I have the phone number and password fields. After filling those, the user clicks on the sign in button, which redirects the user to otp verification page.

```
public class SignUp extends google_abstract {

    ImageView imageView4;
    ImageView imageView5;
    ImageView imageView6;
    TextView textView13;
    EditText phone_no;
    Button sign_up;
    EditText password;

    FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (firebaseUser != null) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SignUp.this, verify_otp.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }
    };

    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(authStateListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        firebaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener(authStateListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);

        imageView4 = findViewById(R.id.imageView4);

        imageView4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                signIn();
            }
        });

        textView13 = findViewById(R.id.textView13);

        phone_no = findViewById(R.id.editText);

        password = findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        textView13.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SignUp.this,verify_otp.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        sign_up = findViewById(R.id.button1);
        sign_up.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String number = phone_no.getText().toString().trim();
                String pass = password.getText().toString();

                if(number.isEmpty()||number.length()<10) {
                    phone_no.setError("Valid Number is required");
                    phone_no.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }
                else if( (pass.length()<8 || pass.length()>12) ){
                    password.setError("must contain min 8 and max 12 characters");
                    password.requestFocus();
                }
                else {
                    String ph_no = "+91"+number;
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SignUp.this, verify_otp.class);
                    intent.putExtra("ph_no", ph_no);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is my verify_otp activity, where the otp is entered and then the user moves in to the profile section :

```
public class verify_otp extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText otp;
    Button button3;
    private String verificationId;
    ProgressBar progressBar_otp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.verify_otp);

        // rsnd = findViewById(R.id.rsnd);

        String phoneNumber = getIntent().getStringExtra("ph_no");
        sendVerificationCode(phoneNumber);

        otp = findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        button3 = findViewById(R.id.button3);
        progressBar_otp = findViewById(R.id.progressBar_otp);

        button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String code = otp.getText().toString().trim();

                if(code.isEmpty()||code.length()<6){
                    otp.setError("Enter code...");
                    otp.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }

                progressBar_otp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                verifyCode(code);
            }
        });

    }


    private void sendVerificationCode(String phoneNumber){
        PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                phoneNumber,
                60,
                TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                TaskExecutors.MAIN_THREAD,
                mCallBack);
    }

    private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
            mCallBack = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

        @Override
        public void onCodeSent(@NonNull String s, @NonNull PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
            super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);
            verificationId=s;
        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(@NonNull PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {

            String code = phoneAuthCredential.getSmsCode();
            if(code!=null){
                progressBar_otp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                verifyCode(code);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(@NonNull FirebaseException e) {
            Toast.makeText(verify_otp.this,e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }

    };

        private void verifyCode(String code) {
            PhoneAuthCredential credential= PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId,code);
            signInWithCredential(credential);
        }


    private void signInWithCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential){

        FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(verify_otp.this ,new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            Intent intent= new Intent(verify_otp.this, tags.class);
                            intent.setFlags((Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK));

                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        else{
                            Toast.makeText(verify_otp.this, task.getException().getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        }
                    }
                });
     }
}
```

This works fine for the first time when the user installs this app but it crashes after the user tries to go to the signUp Activity.

The logcat shows these exceptions:

```
2020-04-23 21:17:04.625 23151-23151/com.sneha.blackcoffer I/zygote: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.sneha.blackcoffer-RQhqJvhXDK8dcBsMOKlvsQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.sneha.blackcoffer-RQhqJvhXDK8dcBsMOKlvsQ==/lib/arm, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]
2020-04-23 21:17:04.627 23151-23151/com.sneha.blackcoffer I/zygote: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.sneha.blackcoffer-RQhqJvhXDK8dcBsMOKlvsQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.sneha.blackcoffer-RQhqJvhXDK8dcBsMOKlvsQ==/lib/arm, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]
2020-04-23 21:17:04.628 23151-23151/com.sneha.blackcoffer I/zygote: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.sneha.blackcoffer-RQhqJvhXDK8dcBsMOKlvsQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.sneha.blackcoffer-RQhqJvhXDK8dcBsMOKlvsQ==/lib/arm, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]
2020-04-23 21:17:04.761 23151-23151/com.sneha.blackcoffer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.sneha.blackcoffer, PID: 23151
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sneha.blackcoffer/com.sneha.blackcoffer.verify_otp}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given String is empty or null
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2974)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3059)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1724)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given String is empty or null
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkNotEmpty(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.1.1:5)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@19.3.0:13)
        at com.sneha.blackcoffer.verify_otp.sendVerificationCode(verify_otp.java:73)
        at com.sneha.blackcoffer.verify_otp.onCreate(verify_otp.java:47)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7258)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7249)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1222)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3059) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1724) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

Line 47 is this 
        sendVerificationCode(phoneNumber);

and, line 73 is this        PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given String is empty
>   or null

Seems like your phoneNumber String is empty or null. You should check it through [**`TextUtils.isEmpty()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils#isEmpty(java.lang.CharSequence)).

```
 String phoneNumber = getIntent().getStringExtra("ph_no");
 if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(phoneNumber))
 {
  sendVerificationCode(phoneNumber);
 }
 else
 {
  //Print your phone number is null or empty
 }
```

Comment: Thank you. Can I ask you one more thing related to this ?